# Transform two-dimensional tables to one-dimensional list in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I am facing the task of querying about 20 parties for numerical data. I will do this via an Excel template. The Excel file is a table with a *x* (2...51) and a *y* (B...M) dimension. Data is to be filled in for each (*x*, *y*) pair.

For evaluation, I would like to unroll the two-dimensional tables into a one-dimensional list, duplicating all *y*-items plus corresponding data for each *x*-item. Kind of "un-pivotizing" the tables. Is there an automatic way of doing this in Excel?

I cannot distribute the one-dimensional list version as this will not be accepted by my peers due to bad usability.

Ultimately, I want to consolidate the data and evaluate it with my own pivot table.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/78439/is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel) will help.

Comment: And along the lines of Mike's answer, see  http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/creating_a_database_table_from_a_summary_table/

Comment: Why not import the data into Microsoft Access and define a query to pull out the data you need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "unpivot" or "reverse pivot" in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/78439/how-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel)