# Place multiple columns onto one line

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, charts, google-docs, google-drive

Let's say I have a table in a spreadsheet that works like a calendar:

```
  Jan Fev Mar ...
1  5   7   1
2  3   4   9
3  8   3   1
4  2   9   0
5  2   1   2
...
```

And so on...

I need to make a chart that puts all these values like they were on a single column (instead of the data being split onto different column there's one column with 365 days) making a single (long) line chart Is this possible?

I rather do this in google drive but excel is fine to.

Regards,
Joaquim Santos

Comment: Check out this question: http://superuser.com/questions/78439/is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel

Comment: Looks similar, will take a look at the answer, thanks