# How do I transpose columns in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this:

[image]

**I want to automatically transform it to this:**

[image]:

I know I can transpose it using this Window:

[image]

But the result is like this:

[image]

How can I get what I described?

Comment: VBA will be the best choice.

Comment: Do you want a solution that will automatically transform it for you, hands-off? If so, @Raystafarian is right, VBA is the way to go.  If you're okay with an approach that just involves laying in formulas by hand, there's a pretty simple way to go about it; I can post an answer if you want.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to "unpivot" the data, as described in this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/78439/is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel).

1. In your case, you'll need to add an extra column so the unpivot process works properly:

   [image: extra column]
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> then <kbd>P</kbd> to start the Pivot Table and Pivot Chart Wizard.
3. Select *Multiple consolidation ranges* and *PivotTable*:

   [image: Step 1 of 3]
4. Select *I will create the page fields*:

   [image: Step 2a of 3]
5. Specify the worksheet range:

   [image: Step 2b of 3]
6. Specify the destination as *New worksheet* and then *Finish*.

   [image: Step 3 of 3]
7. You'll now be presented with a new worksheet (that doesn't look very much like the data you want... yet):

   [image: Intermediate result]
8. Now comes the magic - **double-click on the cell I've highlighted in red - the intersection of the grand totals** and you'll get a new worksheet containing your original data the way you want.

   [image: Final result]

Comment: A very nice answer!

Comment: Very nice indeed