# How do I break up a number in a single cell that doesnt have commas and put it into multiple rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-access

So here is what I am looking to do. I have a spreadsheet with a cell that has a string of numbers in it (some are longer than others) I need to extract every eight numbers and put them into single rows.

Here is what the current spreadsheet looks like:

```
IFIELD1     IFIELD2   IFIELD3     IFIELD4    IMAGELIST
05/30/2009  ERMS      100 Day     L. C.      0000001200000013
05/30/2009  ESE       20 Day      J. R.      0000001400000015
05/30/2009  IHS       100 Day     H. W.      00000016
05/30/2009  LMS       100 Day     D. E.      0000001700000018
```

This is what I am looking to get:

```
IFIELD1     IFIELD2   IFIELD3   IFIELD4   IMAGELIST
05/30/2009  ERMS    100 Day     L. C.     00000012
05/30/2009  ERMS    100 Day     L. C.     00000013
05/30/2009  ESE     20 Day      J. R.     00000014
05/30/2009  ESE     20 Day      J. R.     00000015
05/30/2009  IHS     100 Day     H. W.     00000016
05/30/2009  LMS     100 Day     D. E.     00000017
05/30/2009  LMS     100 Day     D. E.     00000018
```

Some sets off numbers go up to 30 or more groups of 8 in a line. With over 1000 rows of data to separate. Is there any type of code that will help make this process less daunting? I am currently using Left, mid and right but this is going to take me years to finish. The worksheets are coming out of access so if there is an easier way to complete it in there I am open to suggestions. The final product must be saved in a csv. Also I need to keep the entire 8 digits in the completed product prior to saving as a csv so that I can create the link to where that image is located. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you assume that the `IMAGELIST` field value length will always be divisible by 8? I.E., will it always be 8, 16, 24, 32, etc. digits long?

Comment: Isn't this the same question as asked on SO several days ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359585/how-to-split-a-cell/30360572

Comment: @Byron It certainly looks like it, right? The only difference I see is that here it mentions we can find a solution in Access.

Comment: @EngineerToast, maybe they are dumping data from the same vendor system.  Either way, probably going to be the same solution.

Comment: My VBA solution to this is more verbose than the linked SO answer, so I will defer.

Comment: @Byron and Engineer Toast I am sorry I did not see that someone had asked this question already. Also yes the field length will always be divisible by 8. Some total lengths go up to over 2000

Answer (score 0):

There's a fairly easy solution in Access.

1. Create a table that is nothing but a list of numbers: `1, 2, 3, 4, ... n` where `n` is the most number of items that would ever be in your `IMAGELIST`. It's not a very high cost to make it larger than needed, though, so go up to 50 or something.
2. Create a query that pulls in your original table and the numbers table *without any joins*. If you just did `SELECT *` at this point, you'd get `n` copies of every record in your original table.
3. Instead of pulling in the `IMAGELIST` field, add a formula that performs the `MID` function on the `IMAGELIST` field based on the value from your numbers table.
4. Filter to only show records where the formula doesn't return a blank string. This will mean that a record with `IMAGELIST` 24 characters long only shows up 3 times instead of `n` times with a bunch of blank records.

Here's the SQL for that query:

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.IFIELD1, Table1.IFIELD2, Table1.IFIELD3, Table1.IFIELD4, Table2.Number, Mid([IMAGELIST],([Number]-1)*8+1,8) AS ImageListParse
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Mid([IMAGELIST],([Number]-1)*8+1,8)<>""
ORDER BY Table1.ID, Table2.Number;
```

In my quick mockup, `Table1` is your original table, `Table2` is the numbers table, `Number` is the only field in `Table2` and it's just the numbers 1-n, and I added the autonumber field `ID` to `Table1` just for sorting.

This all assumes that every item in `IMAGELIST` is exactly 8 characters. If it varies in length, this approach won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not terribly hard to do with Excel worksheet functions. 
Let’s assume that your data are on `Sheet1` with headers in Row 1. 
Create `Sheet2`.  Fill it in as follows:

- `A1` → `=Sheet1!A1`

  - and drag to the right to cover all the columns
    (i.e., through Column `E`, based on your example of five columns),
  - or simply copy the headers from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2`.
- `A2` → `=OFFSET(Sheet1!A$1, $F2-1, 0)`

  - and drag to the right to cover all the columns *except for* `IMAGELIST`
    (i.e., through Column `D`).
  - At some point you’ll want to format the `Sheet2` columns correctly
    (i.e., the ones that contain dates).
- `E2` → `=LEFT($G2, 8)`
- `F2` → `2`
- `G2` → `=OFFSET(Sheet1!E$1, $F2-1, 0)`

  - (This is the same as the formulas in Columns `A`-`D`,
    except referencing `Sheet1`, Column `E`.)
- `H2` → `=RIGHT($G2, LEN($G2)-8)`

Drag/fill Row 2 to Row 3.  Then change

- `F3` to `=IF(H2<>"", F2, F2+1)`, and
- `G3` to `=IF(H2<>"", H2, OFFSET(Sheet1!E$1, $F3-1, 0))`

Now drag/fill Row 3 down for as many rows as you need
to get all the data from `Sheet1`:

[image]

Then copy and paste values & formats.

#### Explanation:

- Column `F` indicates which row on `Sheet1` *this* row (on `Sheet2`)
  is pulling data from.
- Each time we advance to a new `Sheet1` row
  (i.e., each time Column `F` increases),
  Column `G` gets a complete, 8×*n*-digit-long `IMAGELIST` value
  from `Sheet1`.
- The value in Column `G` gets split:
  first eight digits into Column `E` and the remainder into Column `H`.
- As long as we have a non-empty remainder in Column `H`,
  we copy it into Column `G` and leave Column `F` the same
  (i.e., accessing the same row on `Sheet1`).
- When we run out of data in Column `H`,
  that means we’ve decomposed an 8×*n*-digit-long `IMAGELIST` value
  from `Sheet1` into *n* rows on `Sheet2`,
  so we increment Column `F` and fetch the next `IMAGELIST` value.

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps you need to do to achieve your goal:

1 split the numbers into different columns,e.g. In Excel 2010: Data - text to columns - fixed width - set width to 8 then click finish.

2 2nd step is to unpivot your data, unfortunately it's not simple, but there're are a lot of solutions in the internet, like this: [Is it possible to "unpivot" or "reverse pivot" in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/78439/is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel/888645#888645)