# Non-Standard Transpose in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, transpose

I have a set of horizontal data in Excel that I need vertical. I tried the transpose formula, but when I copy the formula down the next line vertical it is not the following line.

What I need is all the data converted into one vertical line starting on A1-E1, then A2-E2, A3-E3 etc.

The formula I used is: {=TRANSPOSE($A1:$E1)}
When I copy it down the next line says A5:E5 instead of A2:E2.

I have about 3000 lines, so manually it will take forever.

[image]

Comment: it seems from your picture that you aren't looking for a standard transpose, but try to convert all data in one column. Is it right? Please also post the formula you've tried. Please don't respond in answer, but edit your question.

Comment: I cannot understand the question at all. you need to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Excel's `TRANSPOSE` function makes only "exact" transposition, it's not easy to combine with other transformations. Still you've a couple of options:

1. Transpose your data line by line, including only one line in the formula for a time, repeating formula several times. As you have a lot of rows, this one probably isn't for you.
2. Transpose the whole matrix with `TRANSPOSE`, then [un-pivot](https://superuser.com/questions/78439/is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel) the result.
3. Use another formula, e.g.:
   `=INDEX($A$1:$H$5,INT((ROW()-ROW($A$7))/COLUMNS($A$1:$H$5))+1,MOD(ROW()-ROW($A$7),COLUMNS($A$1:$H$5))+1)`

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It didnt work as I hoped it would, but I see that I have not been clear enough. Sorry about that.

I discussed it with a college of mine, and we ended up writing s sub:

Sub TranposeToSheet()
Dim sh As String
sh = "Sheet2"

With ActiveSheet
Max = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
For x = 1 To Max
For y = 1 To 4
    Worksheets(sh).Cells((x * 4) + y, 1) = .Cells(x, y + 1)  ' Value
    Worksheets(sh).Cells((x * 4) + y, 2) = .Cells(x, y + 4 + 1)  ' Price

Next
Next


End With
End Sub

This worked as a peach. 
Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Torstein_norway if you solved it with a macro, please post that as an answer for others to see.