# Creating histogram from matrix data on excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

[image: Distance matrix]

I have a distance matrix as attached in the image whereby the distance between the particles (numbered 1, 2 etc) was listed.

I want to create a histogram of this data and I was wondering if its possible?

Also, is there a way to reorganize this data such that repeated values (since it is symmetrical) can be remove?

Comment: What you've tried? What is your actual problem? How to create a histogram / how to format your data in order to apply a histogram to it? Which version of Excel do you use?

Comment: Hello, my problem would be to format my data so that I could apply a histogram. I'm using Excel 2016.

Comment: look for unpivot e.g. here: https://superuser.com/questions/78439/how-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel

Comment: What criteria you have to format the data and on which data range you are suppose to apply the format. Also for histogram which are Input  & Bin column?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for.. but I want to create a graph where the y axis is the frequency and the x axis the distance

Comment: Creating a histogram in later versions of Excel, requires an Add-In, the Analysis ToolPak.  [Here is a tutorial](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/05/11/make-histogram-excel/) about how to add the ToolPak and create a histogram.

Comment: And [here is how](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2) to remove duplicates.