# How to split comma-separated values for Pivot Table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I have data which has the following format:

```
Electricity
Electricity, Cooling
Electricity, Heat
Electricity, Heat, Cooling
```

I want to use this data in a Pivot Table so I can count the number of items. At the moment, it looks like this:

[image: Pivot table]

I would like to set the Pivot Table so that it reads like the following:

```
Row Labels    |    Count of Energy vectors
Electricity   |                          4
Cooling       |                          2
Heat          |                          2
```

---

How could I set the Pivot Table to achieve the above (or rearrange the data automatically to get the same result)?

Comment: you need to unpivot your data before you can summarize it. look e.g. here: https://superuser.com/questions/78439/how-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel

Comment: @MátéJuhász - Thanks, I'll take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

I am copying a 2018 comment as a community wiki to provide closure to what is technically still an unanswered question:

> you need to unpivot your data before you can summarize it. look e.g.
> here:
> [How to "unpivot" or "reverse pivot" in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/78439/how-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel)