# Excel: from horizontal to vertical arrangement of rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, transpose

to whom it may concern,

I urgently need your expertise on how to flip the data as per below input into output data:

[image: Input and Output data]

I know how the transpose works but it is tedious if we are dealing with hundreds of rows.Iif there is a faster solution for this, it will greatly save a lot of time. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "unpivot" or "reverse pivot" in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/78439/how-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel)

Comment: Transpose + [multiple criteria Index/Match](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/)? What have you tried?

Comment: Power Query will be the best choose for you.

Answer (score 0):

Service Order Number `=INDEX($A$2:$A$100,INT(ROW($A3)/3))`

- where `$A$2:$A$100` is the service order numbers range.
- where `$A3` is Not used to reference a cell's value. Leave `$A3` row reference relative.

Row Headings (Middle Column) `=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MOD(ROW($A3),3)+1)`

- where `$B$1:$D$1` is the column headings.

Row Values `=INDEX($B$2:$D$100,INT(ROW($A3)/3),MOD(ROW($A3),3)+1)`

- where `$B$2:$D$100` is the delivery/fuel/toll data range.

Copy all three formulas to consecutive cells on the same row:
`ServiceOrderNumber | RowHeadings | RowValues`

If these formulas live on a different sheet than the data, be sure to qualify the range with the sheet name: `Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100`

Select All Three Formula Cells. With all three selected, copy drag down together (this way all three formulas are copied down together instead of one at a time).

Why it works:

- The `$A3` cell reference will increment in row value for each row the formula is copied drug down.

  - `ROW` of this incremented row reference will provide numbers: 3,4,5,6,7,8,...
- `INT` of division by 3 will cause every 3 rows to act as one: 1,1,1,2,2,2,...
- `MOD` of 3 will will cycle through columns: 1,2,3,1,2,3,...