# How can I combine a column with a row to generate new columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table

I have data stored as an excel file taken from the U.S. Energy Information Administration. The below is a snippet of that data. I want to transfer this to a GIS-usable format. As such, I want to combine the data in the MSN column by code with the data in the year columns. Take the image below as the current data:

[image]

I want to have a resulting table that looks like this:

[image]

Edit: I've semi-solved this with just a pivot table. I created a pivot table with the MSN codes as Columns, the StateCodes as rows and the year data as a Sum value. If I was only manipulating data in excel, that'd be good enough. The MSN codes are an overall title with each yearly sum a column/title underneath that. Is there a way to combine the overall title with each individual column so that the output resembles the above second image?

Comment: You are looking for UnPivot or Flatten: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "unpivot" or "reverse pivot" in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/78439/how-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel)

Comment: I'm looking through unpivot tutorials and that doesn't seem to quite..fit. There's the additional complication in wanting to create crosstab data based on a third variable. I'll edit the above to try and be more clear.

Comment: I think unpivot is just the start. After you would create a new column concatenate the row and column headers. Then you would repivot and you should get your desired format.

Comment: How about a link to the source. Your example, even if it could be pasted into a worksheet, does not have the information required to produce your desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with `Power Query` aka `Get & Transform`

[image]

with the cursor in the original table

- Data --> Get & Transform Data --> From Table/Range
- The Power Query Editor should open

  - Select the MSN and StateCode columns
  - Unpivot **other** columns

[image]

- Select the `Attribute` column and `replace` `Y` with `_`
- `Merge` the MSN and Attribute columns
- Sort the Merged column or the StateCode if you like
- Select the Merged column and `Pivot`, with the Values column being `Value`, and the aggregate function being `Sum`

  `Close and Load`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've read this correctly and you want another 4 columns to the right, but with combined values, like this:

[image]

Let's call the current columns A to F (as in the picture)

In cell G1 enter the formula `=$B1&C1`

Copy this across the next 3 columns, and the copy all 4 columns down to the bottom of the data

Comment: Meh I dunno, I've reread the question and I don't think it's this actually. Let me know and I'll just delete this answer.

Comment: Not quite! I want to append data in one row to the data in multiple columns to produce new columns. Basically having CLPR1990, CLPR2000, CLPRK2010, etc. The only row would be by the state name, AK, AL, AR, etc.

Comment: Perhaps you could put something into excel manually and show us a screenshot of how it should look?